# Discord.js V13 msg.author.id returning undefined

Tags: discord.js

I have this message, and it has multiple values inside of it, and I'm trying to access the author.id part. I thought I was supposed to do something like msg.author.id, but that just returns undefined.

```
[
  '918149237416558622',
  <ref *1> Message {
    channelId: '918144635782701097',
    guildId: '906210773989203990',
    deleted: false,
    id: '918149237416558622',
    createdTimestamp: 1638974236588,
    type: 'DEFAULT',
    system: false,
    content: 'jamaal',
    author: User {
      id: '346315018696130563',
      bot: false,
      system: false,
      flags: [UserFlags],
      username: 'yAy',
      discriminator: '4998',
      avatar: 'ddaae73d9a3c8ebf564f2dd1c664bcb4',
      banner: undefined,
      accentColor: undefined
    },
    pinned: false,
    tts: false,
    nonce: null,
    embeds: [],
    components: [],
    attachments: Collection(0) [Map] {},
    stickers: Collection(0) [Map] {},
    editedTimestamp: null,
    reactions: ReactionManager { message: [Circular *1] },
    mentions: MessageMentions {
      everyone: false,
      users: Collection(0) [Map] {},
      roles: Collection(0) [Map] {},
      _members: null,
      _channels: null,
      crosspostedChannels: Collection(0) [Map] {},
      repliedUser: null
    },
    webhookId: null,
    groupActivityApplication: null,
    applicationId: null,
    activity: null,
    flags: MessageFlags { bitfield: 0 },
    reference: null,
    interaction: null
]
```

Do I have to add some extra parts or something? I tried doing things like msg[0].author.id, but it still returns undefined either way. Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the answer. I was supposed to do msg[1].author.id instead of msg.author.id